# Can't find vendor/autoload.php for Ratchet

Tags: php, composer-php, ratchet

I SSH'd to my server and installed Composer and Ratchet. http://socketo.me/docs/install claims all I need to do now is include "require **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';" at the top of my php file. My page now gets a "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error.

I've tried various forms of the directory, like "../vendor/autoload.php", but I keep getting the same error. The error reports that it is trying to find it in "/var/www/html/mo/myDomainName.com".

Should I be able to find a vendor folder in my home directory via ftp? I am confused where I'm supposed to be pointing to after my install.

Comment: Composer will install to the path where you run the installer unless you specify `--install-dir`, seems in your case the incorrect place. As Mike says it should be above document root such as `/var/www/vendor`.

Comment: Vendor folder is located at the top the project folder, next to composer.json. public_html is your web-server default project folder for localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typically vendor folder for composer is located above /public_html, so if your script is in public_html folder, you'll have to reference this as up one level

example

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Failed to open stream, and "Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/mo/myDomain.com"

Comment: if you ftp to your server, and go up one level from public_html, do you see the vendor folder?

Comment: No... But the installation over SSH was successful. I have no idea where this vendor folder could be.

Comment: When I installed Composer, I got the message in Terminal "Composer (version 1.10.1) successfully installed to: /home/mo/myDomain.com/composer.phar"

Comment: on my servers vendor folder is at the same level as public_html

Comment: did the command "find . -name vendor -print"
result is "./vendor"
But it is not there when I view via ftp. Hidden system folder?

Comment: tested mine, it also says ./vendor, same level as public_html.  goto that location in ssh and run ls and see if it is there.  mine is visible in ssh and ftp ...  you can also try in ssh 
 ....  ls ./vendor  ... which should produce a directory list

Comment: can you try require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: I can run vendor/autoload.php via SSH, but not ftp.

Comment: Warning: require_once(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/mo/myDomain.com/dir/myPage.php

Comment: try absolute path /home/mo/myDomain.com/vendor/autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Just add base_path(). You will get the actual path of autoload.php C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectFolder\vendor\autoload.php

```
require base_path().'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).